# No me detecta el click sobre los checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una serie de checkbox que básicamente se dividen en:

- Todos los nodos.
- Nodo 1, nodos 2, nodo 3, etc.

Lo que quiero es tener una función que me permita controlar que si la opción de `todos` está seleccionada el resto estén sin selección, y al contrario, si una opción concreta (o varias) está seleccionadas, `todos` no lo esté.

He escrito el siguiente código:

```js
function checkboxController() {
  alert('Hello');
  // Solo permite tener seleccionado o "todos" o nodos sueltos
  $("#todos_nodeFilter").on('click', function() {
    if ($('#todos_nodeFilter').is(':checked')) {
      $(".optionNodeFilter").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  $(".optionNodeFilter").on('click', function() {
    if ($('.optionNodeFilter').is(':checked')) {
      $("#todos_nodeFilter").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Función para controlar comportamiento checkboxes.
  checkboxController();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="todos_nodeLabel"><input type="checkbox" name="Todos_nodos" class="data_filters nodeFilter" id="todos_nodeFilter" checked>Todos</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="Node_1" class="data_filters nodeFilter optionNodeFilter">Nodo 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="Node_2" class="data_filters nodeFilter optionNodeFilter">Nodo 2</label>
```

**EDIT:** Al hacer aquí el snnipet para que pudierais verlo, veo que aquí si funciona perfectamente. Por lo tanto ahora estoy más perdido todavía...

La pregunta es, ¿por qué no me ejecuta la función?

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) con el `html` y el código que has puesto para simular el problema? Dependiendo de la versión de `jQuery` que uses igual tienes que cambiar `.prop()`por `.attr()`

Comment: veo un fallo en tu algoritmo, si todos las opciones están seleccionadas, 'todos' opción debería estarlo también. Lo que no veo es que controles cuántas opciones están seleccionadas. Es decir, si tenemos 10 opciones distintas, más la opción de todos (total 11), no es lo mismo tener 11 seleccionados, que 5, y dentro de esas 5, si la opción todos es una de ellas

Comment: De entrada no me hace falta seleccionar todos si todos están seleccionados, pues la info será misma. Y el control de selecciones es otra función que funciona bien :)

Comment: ¿La versión de `jQuery` utilizada es la misma en el snippet que en tu código? ¿En tu código esos checkbox tienen algún otro evento que pueda estar en conflicto con este?¿Que es exactamente lo que no hace en tu código, llegar al evento, entrar en el if o deseleccionar el check?(Puedes poner un console.log en cada punto para depurar)

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría sería crear dos funciones por separado.

1. La primera llamada `checktodosevent`  para poder detectar cuando el check de `todos` cambia entre checado y no checado.
2. El segundo es `nodoevent` que verifica cuántos elementos totales o nodos existen sin checar, cuando el número de elementos sin checar sea igual al número de nodos total el check de `todos` va a ponerse como checado.

Además, agregué una clase más a cada nodo llamada `item-check` para que se puedan diferenciar más los nodos y el check de todos.

Usé [`prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) de jQuery para alternar el estatus de un checkbox entre activo e inactivo,
aunque por ahí te comentaban que puedes usar `.attr`, aunque estoy usando la misma versión de jQuery que tu código de ejemplo.

```js
function checktodosevent(element) {
  if ( $(element).is(":checked") ) {
    $(".item-check").prop("checked", false);
  }
  else {
    $(".item-check").prop("checked", true);
  }
}


function nodoevent(element) {
  console.log($(".item-check:not(:checked)").length,$(".item-check").length);
  if (  $(".item-check:not(:checked)").length == $(".item-check").length  ) {
    $("#todos_nodeFilter").prop("checked", true);
  }
  else {
    $("#todos_nodeFilter").prop("checked", false);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="todos_nodeLabel"><input type="checkbox" name="Todos_nodos" onchange="checktodosevent(this);" class="data_filters nodeFilter" id="todos_nodeFilter">Todos</label>

<label><input onchange="nodoevent(this);" type="checkbox" name="Node_1" class="item-check data_filters nodeFilter optionNodeFilter" checked>Nodo 1</label>
<label><input onchange="nodoevent(this);" type="checkbox" name="Node_2" class="item-check data_filters nodeFilter optionNodeFilter" checked>Nodo 2</label>
```